# parse.Parse not working

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, json

i am using jquery ajax function ,i  recieve the data from server in the success function but is giving me this error JSON.parse: unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON data ,i verified my json to ensure that server is encoding in correct json format

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "WebForm1.aspx",
            type: "POST",
            datatype: "json",
            success: function(data) {

                var reuslt = $.parseJSON(data);
                alert(reuslt.CustomerID);

            }
        });
    });
```

In WebForm1.aspx

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Customer c = new Customer();
            c.CustomerID = "1";
            c.ContactName = "Jhon";
            c.CompanyName = "Dell";
            JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            String response = serializer.Serialize(c);
            Response.Write(response);

          }
```

Customer Class

```
 public class Customer
    {
        public string CustomerID { get; set; }
        public string CompanyName { get; set; }
        public string ContactName { get; set; }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `dataType: "json"`, in place of `datatype: "json",` (`dataType` should be in `camelCase`)

Read [$.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Comment: i have changed the thing that you mention but still getting error but this time nature of error is different right now i am facing the problem that it goes in error function of ajax and displaying json parsed error

Answer (score 0):

If you use `dataType: 'json'`, no manual parsing is needed. This should be the code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "WebForm1.aspx",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",     //camel case
        success: function(data) {
            var reuslt = data;     //No parsing
            alert(reuslt.CustomerID);
        }
    });
});
```

Cheers

Comment: after making the changes that you had mentioned ,success function not called and in error function following results are displayed readyState=4 and status=200